# Ruby/Rspec Performance Monitor

Tags: ruby, rspec

So I'm working on Rspec problems, and this is the last one I have left. For whatever reason, it's been much harder than all of the others. The three Rspec tests that are in question are as folows:

```
it "runs a block N times" do
  n = 0
  measure(4) do
    n += 1
  end
  n.should == 4
end

it "returns the average time, not the total time, when running multiple times" do
  run_times = [8,6,5,7]
  fake_time = @eleven_am
  Time.stub(:now) { fake_time }
  average_time = measure(4) do
    fake_time += run_times.pop
  end
  average_time.should == 6.5
end

it "returns the average time when running a random number of times for random lengths of time" do
  fake_time = @eleven_am
  Time.stub(:now) { fake_time }
  number_of_times = rand(10) + 2
  average_time = measure(number_of_times) do
    delay = rand(10)
    fake_time += delay
  end
  average_time.should == (fake_time - @eleven_am).to_f/number_of_times
end
```

And my code is as follows:

```
require 'time'
def measure(pass = 0)
  start_time = Time.now
  if pass == 0
    yield
  else
    pass.times {|current| result = yield(current)}
  end
  Time.now - start_time
end
```

(The if/else is present, as an earlier test requires that the code takes one second to execute a program that sleeps for 1 second. In that case, pass would be 0, so the program would jump straight to the yield.)

**Full Rspec [here](https://github.com/alexch/learn_ruby/blob/master/06_performance_monitor/performance_monitor_spec.rb)**

Now, the code DOES pass the 'it "runs  a block N times" do' test, but I feel that the way I have it set up prevents the other two tests from being able to pass. (At the same time, a simple yield won't allow it to pass, because it will get an error from trying to + 1 to nil)

I'm not looking for a copy/paste answer, but moreso whether or not I'm on the right track (Or if my pass.times should be reworked.)

If you have any examples that may be able to lead me in the right direction, I'd be more than happy to see them!

Comment: Note: this is part of the exercise set for App Academy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you "feel" it won't let the other tests pass, do you know this?  I just ran it, and here's the results:

```
Performance Monitor
  takes about 0 seconds to run an empty block
  takes exactly 0 seconds to run an empty block (with stubs)
  takes about 1 second to run a block that sleeps for 1 second
  takes exactly 1 second to run a block that sleeps for 1 second (with stubs)
  runs a block N times
  returns the average time, not the total time, when running multiple times (FAILED - 1)
```

So the last spec fails.  Looks like it's just returning the wrong value, it doesn't look at whether there were multiple passes.  So updating that:

```
require 'time'
def measure(pass = 0)
  start_time = Time.now
  if pass == 0
    yield
  else
    pass.times {|current| result = yield(current)}
  end
  (Time.now - start_time) / (pass == 0 ? 1 : pass)
end
```

Now running the specs shows me:

```
(in /Users/nick/learn_ruby)

Performance Monitor
  takes about 0 seconds to run an empty block
  takes exactly 0 seconds to run an empty block (with stubs)
  takes about 1 second to run a block that sleeps for 1 second
  takes exactly 1 second to run a block that sleeps for 1 second (with stubs)
  runs a block N times
  returns the average time, not the total time, when running multiple times
  returns the average time when running a random number of times for random lengths of time

Finished in 1.01 seconds
7 examples, 0 failures
```

Great part about testing first is you can just *find out* if what you are doing is wrong, and then fix it.

Comment: Ah, such a simple solution. .-. I've used the Ternary Operator in quite a few of the other Rspecs, but I completely forgot about it here. ;O  In my head, I was thinking that it was an error of the yield statement, but I guess I wasn't exactly understanding the Rspec completely. I do thank you for your help though! I was so close, but had a small misunderstanding about the process, but you're answer has made it much clearer. Thanks a lot! c:

Comment: No need to require 'time'.

Answer (score 1):

```
def measure(pass = 1)
    start_time = Time.now
    pass.times {yield}
    (Time.now - start_time) / (pass)
end
```

for any future passerbys, this could be written more efficiently like so, using a default value of 1 for pass